# Print current iteration in while loop

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, heredoc

I have following line in my script, `${snap[@]}` array contain my ssh server list.

```
      while IFS= read -r con; do
    ssh foo@"$con" /bin/bash <<- EOF
      echo "Current server is $con"
EOF
      done <<< "${snap[@]}"
```

I want to print current iteration value of the array as the ssh ran successfully, the `$con` should print current ssh server --> `example@`**`server`**. How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this :

```
while IFS= read -r con; do
    ssh "foo@$con" /bin/bash <<EOF
        echo "Current server is $con"
EOF
done < <(printf '%s\n' "${snap[@]}")
#    ____
#      ^
#      |
# bash process substitution < <( )
```

Or simply :

```
for server in "${snap[@]}"; do
    ssh "foo@$con" /bin/bash <<EOF
        echo "Current server is $con"
EOF
done
```

Comment: It seems overcomplicated to use a combination of `printf` and a `while read` loop to iterate over the contents of an array.

Comment: @TomFenech yes, added `for loop` version

Answer (score 2):

If the elements in `snap` are the hosts that you want to connect to, just use a `for` loop:

```
for con in "${snap[@]}"; do
  # connect to "$con"
done
```

`"${snap[@]}"` expands to the safely-quoted list of elements in the array `snap`, suitable for use with `for`.

If you really want to use `while`, then you can do something like this:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#snap[@]} ]; do # while i is less than the length of the array
  # connect to "${snap[i]}"
  i=$(( i + 1 ))                 # increment i
done
```

But as you can see, it's more awkward than the `for`-based approach.

Comment: I know `for` loops can do this, but I'm looking a `while` solution, thanks.

Comment: I would strongly recommend the approach using `for`, but I have added an option using `while` anyway.

Comment: Why would you use a `while` loop when the `for` loop is clearly called for?

Comment: You don't need to use `set`; you can just use a `while` loop to produce increasing values of `i` that can be used to index `snap`.

Comment: @chepner yeah you're right, I replaced my example with that simpler option, thanks.